# Refreshing a jQuery Mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to refresh a jQuery Mobile page using `location.reload(true)`, however in this particular jQuery Mobile view I need a variable to persist through the refresh. Does anybody know how I might accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you re-get the page, and include the variable as part of the query string?

Comment: @MikeHedman I'm thinking about just using cookies and sessionStorage actually..

Comment: If you can presume that cookies are allowed, or html5 is supported, then certainly that's the cleanest way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use 'pageshow' instead of location.reload(true).

```
$("#dividofpagecontainer").trigger('pageshow');
```

It helps me to when i struggle with same page refreshing.